# System.ArgumentNullException when awaiting IObservable

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin, system.reactive

I am trying to await an Observable and I Get a

> System.ArgumentNullException
>
> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: Source

The stack trace:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
  at System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.GetAwaiter[TSource] (System.IObservable`1[T] source) [0x00003] in <370f6a6bb34048878534065376a195cb>:0
  at Lynkd.Models.Peripherals.RPHPeripheral+<readMacAddress>d__13.MoveNext () [0x00012] in /Users/ericbowman/Documents/Development/Mobile/LYNKD/Lynkd/Models/Peripherals/RPHPeripheral.cs:24
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113
  at Lynkd.Models.Peripherals.RPHGunbox+<InitializeAsync>d__1.MoveNext () [0x00020] in /Users/ericbowman/Documents/Development/Mobile/LYNKD/Lynkd/Models/Peripherals/RPHGunbox.cs:12
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1018
  at UIKit.UIKitSynchronizationContext+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIKitSynchronizationContext.cs:24
  at Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSAction.cs:125
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
  at Lynkd.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/ericbowman/Documents/Development/Mobile/LYNKD/Lynkd.iOS/Main.cs:17
```

Here is my source:

```
protected async Task readMacAddress()
{
    await (Device.ReadCharacteristic(BleService.DeviceInformation, BleCharacteristic.MacAddress).Subscribe(
        onNext: Result =>
        {
            MacAddress = BitConverter.ToString(Result.Data).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        },
        onError: Error =>
        {
            throw new BleException("Cannot Retrive MAC Address, Error Reading MAC Address");
        },
        onCompleted: () =>
        {
            return;

    }) as IObservable<CharacteristicGattResult>);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that since it's reading a bluetooth characteristic from our own in-house peripheral. I may be able to do it with some other generic peripheral that a lot of people have? It may be necessary but it would be a few hours work so I'm going to hold off on that for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was WAY overthinking the use of RX. You can simply await the original function call like so:

```
protected async Task readMacAddress()
{
    var macResult = await Device.ReadCharacteristic(BleService.DeviceInformation, BleCharacteristic.MacAddress);
    MacAddress = BitConverter.ToString(macResult.Data).Replace("-", string.Empty);
}
```

Big thanks to Allan Ritchie for steering me in the right direction. (the author of the handy Xamarin BLE library I'm using) https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the API, but I'm going to venture that the type of the values is not `CharacteristicGattResult`.

Could it be BluetoothGattCharacteristic`?

Comment: good guess; but that is the correct type. I posted it as an issue on the GitHub page for the writer of the bluetooth library. He has indicated that my code is just plain wrong and I've asked for clarification.